# I am new in springboot, i am getting error while working on sts

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I am using Jpa repository in the code, and my code looks like this.

**com.example.demo**  ->

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("com.example.demo.model")
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**com.example.demo.controller**  ->

```java
package com.example.demo.controller;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demo.model.Employee;
import com.example.demo.service.EmployeeService;
//@Controller
@RestController      //@controller+@ResponseBody
public class EmployeeController {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService eService;
//  @RequestMapping(value = "/employees",method = RequestMethod.GET)
//  @ResponseBody
    @GetMapping("/employees")
    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return eService.getEmployees();
    }
    @GetMapping("/employee/{id}")
    public String getEmployee(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return "Details for: "+id;
    }
    @PostMapping("/employees")
    public String saveEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        return "Saving employee details to the db "+ employee;
    }
    @PutMapping("/employee/{id}")
    public Employee updateemployee(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Employee employee) {
        System.out.print("Update details for"+id);
        return employee;
    }
    @DeleteMapping ("/employee")
    public String deleteEmployee(@RequestParam Long id) {
        return "Details for: "+id;
    }
}
```

**com.example.demo.model**       ->

```java
package com.example.demo.model;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name="age")
    private Long age;
    
    @Column(name="location")
    private String location;
    
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;
    
    @Column(name="department")
    private String department;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Long getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(Long age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", location=" + location + ", email=" + email
                + ", department=" + department + "]";
    }
    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }
    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }
}
```

**com.example.demo.repository** ->

```java
package com.example.demo.repository;

    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    import com.example.demo.model.Employee;
    
    @Repository
    public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
    
    }
```

**com.example.demo.service**       ->

[image]

(interface)

[image]

(Implementation)

**pom file**                                     ->

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here I am just trying to return an empty list via(*@GetMapping*("/employees")) but it is showing error like below

```
[2m2023-10-29T12:19:17.956+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5216[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.example.demo.DemoApplication        [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting DemoApplication using Java 17.0.8.1 with PID 5216 (C:\Users\parit\Documents\demo\target\classes started by parit in C:\Users\parit\Documents\demo)
[2m2023-10-29T12:19:17.959+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5216[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.example.demo.DemoApplication        [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
[2m2023-10-29T12:19:18.003+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5216[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36m.e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
[2m2023-10-29T12:19:18.003+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5216[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36m.e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor[0;39m [2m:[0;39m For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
[2m2023-10-29T12:19:18.732+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5216[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
[2m2023-10-29T12:19:18.785+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5216[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 44 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
[2m2023-10-29T12:19:20.254+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5216[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
[2m2023-10-29T12:19:20.264+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5216[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service [Tomcat]
[2m2023-10-29T12:19:20.264+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5216[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.15]
[2m2023-10-29T12:19:20.339+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5216[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[2m2023-10-29T12:19:20.340+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5216[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mw.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2337 ms
[2m2023-10-29T12:19:20.452+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5216[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Starting...
[2m2023-10-29T12:19:20.756+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5216[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@36041206
[2m2023-10-29T12:19:20.758+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5216[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
[2m2023-10-29T12:19:20.803+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5216[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
[2m2023-10-29T12:19:20.895+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5216[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.Version                   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.2.13.Final
[2m2023-10-29T12:19:20.898+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5216[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.cfg.Environment           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000406: Using bytecode reflection optimizer
[2m2023-10-29T12:19:21.277+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5216[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
[2m2023-10-29T12:19:21.659+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5216[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
[2m2023-10-29T12:19:21.665+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5216[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[2m2023-10-29T12:19:21.792+05:30[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m5216[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'eService': Error creating bean with name 'employeeServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'eRepository': Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository' defined in com.example.demo.repository.EmployeeRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.example.demo.model.Employee
[2m2023-10-29T12:19:21.793+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5216[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[2m2023-10-29T12:19:21.796+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5216[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
[2m2023-10-29T12:19:21.804+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5216[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
[2m2023-10-29T12:19:21.805+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5216[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Stopping service [Tomcat]
[2m2023-10-29T12:19:21.816+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5216[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36m.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger[0;39m [2m:[0;39m 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2m2023-10-29T12:19:21.834+05:30[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m5216[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'eService': Error creating bean with name 'employeeServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'eRepository': Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository' defined in com.example.demo.repository.EmployeeRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.example.demo.model.Employee
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:767) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:747) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:492) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1416) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:950) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:738) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:440) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'eRepository': Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository' defined in com.example.demo.repository.EmployeeRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.example.demo.model.Employee
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:767) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:747) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:492) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1416) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:764) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository' defined in com.example.demo.repository.EmployeeRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.example.demo.model.Employee
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:764) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.demo.model.Employee
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.managedType(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:467) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:82) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:69) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:246) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:211) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:194) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:245) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1817) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
```

Why it is giving error?

Comment: Replace screenshots to code

Answer (score 2):

With that version of Java and Spring Boot you should be using the jakarta library and not javax. Remove the javax dependency, remove @EntityScan, and refactor your Employee class to use the jakarta library and that should fix things and make Employee discoverable by @SpringBootApplication.

Comment: Thanks, that is woking.
But in the employeeService. when I am trying to return eRepository.findAll() , jpaRepository is not showing up.
I am able to use ListCrudRepository() but not jpaRepository().

Comment: can you refer this [code](https://github.com/vasant-techie/so-jpa-entity-solution/blob/main/src/main/java/com/example/demo/service/EmployeeService.java) and verify whether your Service class code matches with this

Comment: Yes, it matches. My service class code lools like this `https://github.com/mathur-12/stackoverflow-doubt/blob/main/serviceclass`.
I am not able to see jpaRepository options linked to Employee class.

Comment: `@Autowired` annotation should be mentioned above `EmployeeRepository eRepository;`

Answer (score 1):

As rightly mentioned by @TimurCelikel, solution is to,

1. Replace `javax.persistence` with `jakarta.persistence`
2. Remove `@EntityScan("com.example.demo.model")`

***UPDATED ENTITY CLASS***

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
```

**Service class**

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import com.example.demo.repository.EmployeeRepository;
import com.example.demo.model.Employee;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class EmployeeService {

    EmployeeRepository empRepo;

    @Autowired
    public EmployeeService(EmployeeRepository empRepo) {
        this.empRepo = empRepo;
    }
    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return empRepo.findAll();
    }
}
```

Entire code can be referred [here](https://github.com/vasant-techie/so-jpa-entity-solution).

Answer (score 0):

As per the exception you can see while creating beans you are getting error. This is because you have used **@EntityScan** so, IOC will scan only the class which will have **@Entity** and only those bean will be available in IOC. And it will not scan all other classes and bean of other classes will not generate in IOC. So, for making this application to work you must use **@ComponentScan**

You can read about the differences of @EntityScan and @ComponentScan here
[differences](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-entityscan-vs-componentscan)

Comment: `SpringBootApplication` should already be scanning all the classes from the base package